# Is it possible to have multiple operator& in a class?

Tags: c++

I was trying to express a interface where two interfaces composite the same thing, and inherited (single inheritance) by the implementation. The idea is composition over inheritance from the interface class itself. It is something like this:

```
class A_interface;
class B_interface {
public:
    B_interface(const B_interface& a) = delete;
    B_interface& operator=(const B_interface& a) = delete;
    virtual operator A_interface&() = 0;
protected:
    B_interface() = default;
};

class A_interface {
public:
    A_interface(const A_interface& a) = delete;
    A_interface& operator=(const A_interface& a) = delete;
    virtual operator B_interface&() = 0;
    void afunc()
    {
        printf("Hello from base A\n");
    }
protected:
    A_interface() = default;
};

class B_Impl;
class A_Impl: public A_interface {
public:
    operator B_Impl&();
    virtual operator B_interface&() override;
protected:
    friend B_Impl;
    A_Impl() = default;
};

class B_Impl:public B_interface {
public:
    B_Impl()=default;
    operator A_Impl&();
    virtual operator A_interface&() override;
private:
    A_Impl a;
};


A_Impl::operator B_Impl&()
{
    printf("Hello from A_Impl::operator B_Impl&\n");
    return *(B_Impl*)(((uint8_t*)this)-offsetof(B_Impl, B_Impl::a));
}

A_Impl::operator B_interface&()
{
    printf("Hello from A_Impl::operator B_interface&\n");
    return A_Impl::operator B_Impl&();
}

B_Impl::operator A_Impl&()
{
    printf("Hello from B_Impl::operator A_Impl&\n");
    return a;
}

B_Impl::operator A_interface&()
{
    printf("Hello from B_Impl::operator A_interface&\n");
    return B_Impl::operator A_Impl & ();
}
```

Now from the outside code:

```
B_Impl b;
b.operator A_interface &().operator B_interface &().operator A_interface &().afunc();
A_interface& a1 = b;
```

Output is:

```
Hello from B_Impl::operator A_interface&
Hello from B_Impl::operator A_Impl&
Hello from A_Impl::operator B_interface&
Hello from A_Impl::operator B_Impl&
Hello from B_Impl::operator A_interface&
Hello from B_Impl::operator A_Impl&
Hello from base A
Hello from B_Impl::operator A_interface&
Hello from B_Impl::operator A_Impl&
```

Now the question:
What do I need to overload to make the following code work?

```
A_interface* a2 = &b;
```

Comment: Why not using `A_interface& a2 = b;`?

Comment: `A_interface* a2 = &static_cast<A_interface&>(b);`?

Comment: You might overload (evil) `unary operator&` to return object which has `operator A_interface*()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literal *overloading* requires an argument to overload on, but this is the *unary* `operator&`. You seem to want to overload on the return type, not the argument.

For that, you need to return a proxy type which has implicit conversions to both `A_interface*` and `B_interface*`. These need to be members of the proxy, since you obviously cannot add a constructor to `A_interface*`. Pointers are built-in types and do not have any member functions, let alone user-defined member types.

Comment: Then what if my declaration is just to declare that A and B are mutually convertible interfaces, The implementation is away from the declaration. The pointer type has to be instantiated in the base A and base B to be usable, but that makes the derived always use the base pointer type,

Comment: @shangjiaxuan: I don't understand what you're getting at. The declaration of `proxy::operator A_interface*` only requires a forward declaration of `class A_interface;`. How it works behind the scenes is not part of the public interface of `proxy`. Similarly, the definition of `proxy A::operator&` only requires a forward declaration `class proxy;`.